# meaning of parameter list in function prototype "function(arg1,arg2[,arg3[,arg4]])"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming

i'm learning Python2.7 network programming, there's a API socket.getaddrinfo(host,port[,family[,socktype[,proto[,flags]]]]),wondering what's the meaning of the parameter list like this?

```
socket.getaddrinfo(host,port[,family[,socktype[,proto[,flags]]]])

import socket
socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Documentation:-

functionName(function_arguments, [optional_arguments])

- function_arguments - represents the normal arguments which need to be passed while calling the function. They are always left.
- optional_arguments - represents the arguments, whose values can be passed or omitted while calling the function as per needs. They are always right side.

Therefore in `socket.getaddrinfo(host,port[,family[,socktype[,proto[,flags]]]])` method -
`family`, `socktype`, `proto` and `flags` are optional arguments. Function will address them according to their positions

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude :)